# Why is multiplication well defined in this ring with the Ore condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading *Linear Equations in Non-Commutative Fields* by Oystein Ore in the Annals of Mathematics. The papers is available [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/i307168) or [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/1968245.pdf?acceptTC=true) if one has access to jstor.

Ore is working in a noncommutative domain, such that any two nonzero elements have a common right multiple. Ore defines equality of fractions as follows:

> Let $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{a_1}{b_1}$ be two arbitrary fractions. The elements $\beta\neq 0$ and $\beta_1\neq 0$ can be determined so that
>   $$
> b\beta_1=b_1\beta
> $$
>   and we say 
>   $$
> \frac{a}{b}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}
> $$
>   when $a\beta_1=a_1\beta$.

On page 468, (page 6 of the paper), Ore defines multiplication as
$$
\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a\alpha_1}{b_1\beta}
$$
where $b\alpha_1=a_1\beta,\beta\neq 0$, and states that "simple calculations" show this is well defined. Can someone please help me show it is well defined? I let
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'},\qquad\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_1'}{b_1'}.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a\lambda}{b_1\mu},\qquad\text{ where }b\lambda=a_1\mu
$$
and
$$
\frac{a'}{b'}\cdot\frac{a_1'}{b_1'}=\frac{a'\lambda'}{b_1'\mu'},\qquad\text{ where }b'\lambda'=a_1'\mu'.
$$

I use the common multiple property to find $\sigma$ and $\rho$ such that $b_1\mu\sigma=b_1'\mu'\rho$. It then follows that the above two fractions are equal if $a\lambda\sigma=a'\lambda'\rho$, which would follow from $b\lambda\sigma=b'\lambda'\rho$, since $a/b=a'/b'$. However, I don't know how to get further. What is the simple calculation I'm overlooking? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the other references dealing with noncommutative localization?

Answer (score 1):

$$
b_1\mu\sigma=b_1'\mu'\rho \implies\\
a_1\mu\sigma=a_1'\mu'\rho \implies\\
b\lambda\sigma = b'\lambda'\rho \implies\\
a\lambda\sigma=a'\lambda'\rho
$$